# Name field of Group sObject is Not Nillable but returns null

Tags: rest-api, metadata, sobject, describesobject

I request the metadata for the sObject Group via:

```
GET /services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Group/describe/ HTTP/1.1
```

In the resulting JSON i see the following metadata at the fields property:

```
{
      ...
      "name": "Name",
      ...
      "nillable": false,

 }
```

From this and from the documentation:
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_organization.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_objects_organization.htm|SkinName=webhelp

The column should not be nilable.
But when i make the following request:

```
GET /services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT%20Name%20FROM%20Group HTTP/1.1
```

I get the following record answear:

```
{
  "totalSize": 37,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Group",
        "url": "\/services\/data\/v32.0\/sobjects\/Group\/00G24000000VIWqEAO"
      },
      "Name": null
    },
...
```

Is this behaviour known? Is this just the case because i'm working against the test-system of salesforce? Do other tables suffer the same table or should i not trust the metadata??

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the documentation, [`Group.Name`](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) is required.

> **Name**
> *Type*: string
> *Properties*: Create, Filter, Group, Sort, Update
> *Description*: **Required.** Name of the group. Corresponds to Label on the user interface.

As you found, the Metadata on this field also reports `nillable = false`.

[image: What if I told you... Group.Name being required was a lie!]

At least as far as you are concerned for Groups you can create or edit the Name field is indeed required. However, there are certain system-defined groups that also appear when you query Group.

From [Group Maintenance Tables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.meta/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood/uth_groups.htm) (my emphasis)

> **Group Maintenance Tables**
>
> Sharing rows grant access to users and groups, but the data that specifies who belongs to each group resides in the Group Maintenance tables. These tables store membership data for every Salesforce group, including *system-defined groups*. **System-defined groups are groups of users that Salesforce creates and manages internally to support various features and behaviors**, such as queues. This type of management lets the data that supports queues and personal or public groups coexist in the same database tables, and unifies how Salesforce manages the data. For example, Salesforce can grant record access to a queue the same way it grants record access to a public group.
>
> Salesforce also uses system-defined groups to implement hierarchies. During recalculation, **Salesforce creates two types of system-defined groups, *Role* groups and *RoleAndSubordinates* groups, for every node in the role hierarchy.** If the organization has external organization-wide defaults enabled, a third type of system-defined group, RoleAndInternalSubordinates, is created.

If you add `Type` and `OwnerId` to the SOQL query you should see that when the Name is null the Type will indicate that it is system defined, such as Role, RoleAndSubordinates, and Organization. The `OwnerId` will also be the Org Id rather than a User Id.

[image]

Comment: so basically ... i cannot 100% sure that nilable=false guarantees me that on null values may come, as salesforce internally may have null values.
Usually, it is the case, but it may not be?

Comment: @kamahl correct. The meta data is correct the majority of the time, but there are always exceptions to the rule. You often see records in a Data Export that don't conform to the current meta data schema definition. This can happen over time with schema changes. In this case, an internal Salesforce process isn't following their defined schema.

Comment: Thank you :).
Sadly, this makes data-integration from the rest-api to BI not so funny.